# Identify duplicates and mark first occurrence and all others

Tags: r, duplicates

I'm trying to identify all rows which are represented twice or more in a matrix.

For example:

```
m <- matrix(c(1,2,1,3,1,4,1,2,2,3,2,3,1,2,5), ncol = 3)
m
duplicated(m[,1])
```

Outputs:

```
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    4    2
[2,]    2    1    3
[3,]    1    2    1
[4,]    3    2    2
[5,]    1    3    5

[1] FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE
```

However, I do not want that output.  I want:

```
[1] TRUE FALSE TRUE FALSE TRUE
```

since row[1,1]'s value appears 3 times in m's column 1.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

When I saw this question I  asked myself "what would Jim Holtman or Bill Dunlap advise on Rhelp?". Haven't looked in the archives, but I think they might have advised using two "parallel" applications of `duplicated`, one with the defaults and one with the `fromLast` parameter and conjoining with a vector OR (`|`) operator.

```
duplicated(m[,1]) | duplicated(m[,1], fromLast=TRUE)
[1]  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE
```

Comment: This should be a parameter of `duplicated()` lest we end up with such a convoluted command.

Comment: I'm not sure this is teh right place to ask for modification of the language. Another option might be `m[,1] %in% duplicated(m[,1])`. Does that seem more natural to you?

Answer (score 3):

Here's one approach of many:

```
m <- matrix(c(1,2,1,3,1,4,1,2,2,3,2,3,1,2,5), ncol = 3)

x <- table(m[,1])
as.character(m[,1]) %in% names(x)[x > 1]

## > as.character(m[,1]) %in% names(x)[x > 1]
## [1]  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE

# or wrap it up as function:

FUN <- function(vec) {
    x <- table(vec)
    as.character(vec) %in% names(x)[x > 1]
}

FUN(m[, 1])

## > FUN(m[, 1])
## [1]  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE
```

Comment: Is there a reason for the call to `sort`?

Comment: Yes I started off by using `rle` and decided against that.  So yes but no longer.  I deleted it out of the response.

Comment: Thanks for the help.  I tried both out and they both worked successfully.

Comment: @user2329658 if they both worked perfectly don't be afraid to upvote good answers and *give* something back to the community! (if you want) :-)

Comment: @SimonO101.  Thanks for the tips.  I just tried upvoting, I think I need to get some street cred in the form of reputation points first.

Comment: @user2329658 you are right - you need 15 rep. I have sent you on your way by upvoting your question, because you provided a nice reproducible example. Welcome to SO! :-)